# Entering data as a checkbox or edit in mysqli database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Hi in the past few days i have learnt how to input data via a form and show records (basic i know lol)

But i am wanted to enter data or edit it as check boxes how would i do this?

```
<label class="control-label" for="checklist"> My Checklist</label>

<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist" value="yes">
job number 1 </label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist" value="yes">
job number 2 </label>
```

Would this have to be separate columns? Like job_1 and job_2?

with my other entry’s i use this code to display the record

```
<?php echo$ENTRY; ?>
```

How would i display these so it shows as a ticked or un-ticked check-box depending on the entry of yes?

Please be kind with your answers I’m novice try not to confuse me more than i already am :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[]" value="yes">
```

The above allows a checklist array;

also to ticked or unticked can be done by

```
$jobs = array('cooking','washing','shopping','cleaning','grooming'); // Define however you like.
$checkedResultsArray = array(1,2,5); // DB to get this list

foreach($jobs as $k => $job) {
    $checked = '';
    if(in_array($job, $checkedResultsArray)) {
        $checked = 'checked'; // in_array() checks to see if the $job number is in our array of checked results. I presume you save these to a DB, so you can retrieve them from there too.
    }

    echo '<label class="checkbox">';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checklist[' . $job . ']" value="yes" ' . $checked . '>';    
    echo 'Job Number ' . $k . ' : ' . $job . ' </label><br />';
}
```

To see how this all looks print out your POST/GET variables, depending on which you're using for the form.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "<pre>";
```

It will help it all make a lot more sense. Especially once you submit your form

Comment: @RickNash No worries, you can actually test that middle chunk of code out on http://writecodeonline.com/php/  to see it works.

Comment: Thank you for this but i have a few questions regrading your answer. the top bit of code should replace mine? as my value is 'yes' does that mean i have to change it to 'checked' also this prints out job number 1 job number 2, ect ect is there a way to make it print custom for each tick?

Comment: forget that last bit i figured out how to custom print :)

but to the rest i still dont know

Comment: @RickNash What defines job number? And where do you save it once they submit the form?

Comment: There 5 different tasks ie cooking, washing up, food shopping, that's why i asked do i need separate coloums

Comment: @RickNash So perhaps change $job_count = array(1,2,3,4,5); to $job_count = array('cooking','washing','shopping','cleaning','grooming');